# Check two NSArrays for containing each other's objects (NSManagedObject)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm stuck at following problem for quite some time now:
I've got two NSArrays, both containing NSManagedObject subclass-objects.
They're fed by different sources but the objects in them still have the same properties/values.
What I want to do now is check if array A contains objects from array B and vice versa.
Unfortunately NSArray's containsObject-method doesn't seem to work here.
I think it uses id-testing for the equality check on each object, doesn't it?

So, does anybody have a clue, what to try?

I even tried to encapsulate my objects in NSSets, using member: as my comparison-method but this didn't work out as well, especially because "you must not override" isEqual etc. for NSManagedObject subclasses.

Here's a code snippet:

```
//manufacturers is an array, parsed out of some xml here...

for(Manufacturer *manu in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
{
    if(![manufacturers containsObject:manu])
    {
        NSLog(@"Deleting %@", manu.name);
        [self.mContext deleteObject:manu];
    }
}

for(Manufacturer *manu in manufacturers)
{
    if(![[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] containsObject:manu])
    {
        NSLog(@"Adding %@", manu.name);
        [newArray addObject:manu];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, but you could try to match the dictionaries you get with `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`.

Something like this:

```
NSArray *keysToCompare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"FooAttribute", @"BarAttribute", nil];

// create an array with the dictionary representation of the managedObject
NSMutableArray *fetchedObjectsDictionaries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]];
for (NSManagedObject *object in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionaryRepresentation = [object dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keysToCompare];
    [fetchedObjectsDictionaries addObject:dictionaryRepresentation];
}

// another array with dictionaries for managedObjects
NSMutableArray *manufacturersDictionaries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[manufacturers count]];
for (NSManagedObject *object in manufacturers) {
    NSDictionary *dictionaryRepresentation = [object dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keysToCompare];
    [manufacturersDictionaries addObject:dictionaryRepresentation];
}

// compare those dictionaries
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [fetchedObjectsDictionaries count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [fetchedObjectsDictionaries objectAtIndex:i];
    if (![manufacturersDictionaries containsObject:dictionary]) {
        // get the corresponding managedObject
        NSManagedObject *object = [[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
        [newArray addObject:object];
    }
}
```

---

if that won't work you can write your own `isEqualToManufacturer:` method and enumerate trough the arrays manually.

Comment: This is very expensive and slow if those arrays contain more than a few objects.

Answer (score 0):

There would be 3 types of equality you can check for: same memory address, managed object id equality, and value equality. Your current code already checks to see if the objects share the same memory address and this is most likely not what you are interested in. This leaves two possible options. Using the managed object id equality method you can check if the manufacturers point to the same row in the database. Using the value equality you can check if two manufacturers are equal based on the shared values. Below is a way to check for NSManagedObjectID equality.

```
for(Manufacturer *manu in [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
{
    id databaseIDTest = ^(Manufacturer * checkManu, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        return [[checkManu objectID] isEqual:[manu objectID]];
    };

    if([manufacturers indexOfObjectPassingTest:databaseIDTest] == NSIndexNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Deleting %@", manu.name);
        [self.mContext deleteObject:manu];
    }
}

for(Manufacturer *manu in manufacturers)
{
    id databaseIDTest = ^(Manufacturer * checkManu, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        return [[checkManu objectID] isEqual:[manu objectID]];
    };
    NSArray * fetchedObjects = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    if([fetchedObjects indexOfObjectPassingTest:databaseIDTest] == NSIndexNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Adding %@", manu.name);
        [newArray addObject:manu];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. Since you're in the same context, comparing two pointers (memory addresses) and comparing two managed object IDs effectively does the same thing, but comparing two pointers is a **lot** cheaper (orders of magnitude).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but this doesn't seem to work as well... Think I might have to iterate over my array by hand and count occurences. At least this is the only way left I could think of to test the objects "my way".

Answer (score -2):

You need to override `-isEqual:` since that's what `-[NSArray containsObject:]` calls into:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other;
{
    if (![other isKindOfClass:[Manufacturer class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    Manufacturer *otherManufacturer = other;
    return ([self.name isEqual:otherManufacturer.name] &&
           ...
           );
}
```

Checking for containment inside an NSSet is cheaper (and may make sense if you run into performance problems). It only works if you have a relatively decent `-hash` implementation, but it's easy to implement like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash;
{
    return [self.name hash] + [self.foo hash] + ...;
}
```

Don't go trough too much trouble with the hash, just use 2 - 3 values that are *most likely* to uniquely identify the object.

Comment: I'd love to be able to simply override my objects' comparison method but since I'm using NSManagedObject subclasses I can't. Otherwise this would've been the best solution for sure ;)